# Unable to find getPrice method in catalog

Tags: magento2, price, special-price, totals, function

Simple issue but can't figure it out alone :

Under base `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/template/product/price/special_price.html`

There is this part that is used to calculated the product total

```
<span class="price-wrapper"
              css="priceWrapperCssClasses"
              attr="priceWrapperAttr"
              data-price-amount=""
              data-price-type="finalPrice"
              html="getPrice($row())"/>
```

My problem is that I'm unable to see what is really executed, where is the getPrice method. Cause I need to add a certain amount on that price.

As you can see my total takes the first values but not the last one I just added :

[image: prices total]

Comment: Try: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/product/list/columns/final-price.js

Comment: @jiheison Sadly, I don't think it's coming from there, I've tried to console log the getPrice inside but nothing were logged.